# copy csv file from multiple directories to a new one in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to extract many .csv files from multiple directories/subdirectories and copy them in a new folder, where I would like to end up with only .csv files.

The csv files are stored in subdirectories with the following structure:

```
D:\R data\main_folder\03\07\04\BBB_0120180307031414614.csv
D:\R data\main_folder\03\07\05\BBB_0120180307031414615.csv
```

I am trying the list.files function to extract the csv files names only.

```
my_dirs <- list.files("D:\\R data\\main_folder\\",pattern="\\.csv$" ,recursive = TRUE, 
                      include.dirs = FALSE,full.names = FALSE)
```

The problem is that csv files are listed with the directory path, e.g.

```
03/07/03/BBB_0120180307031414614.csv
```

And this, even though full.names and include.dirs is set to FALSE.
This prevents me from copying those files in a new folder, as the name is not recognized.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `basename` function coupled with `list.files` like below.

If I understood you correctly then you want to fetch the names of **.csv** files present in different directory.

I have made a **temp** folder in my documents directory of windows machine , Inside that I have two folders "one" and "two", Inside these folders I have csv files named as "just_one.csv" and "just_two.csv".

So If I want to fetch the names "just_one.csv" and "just_two.csv" then I could do this:

```
basename(list.files("C:/Users/C_Nfdl_99878314/Documents/temp", "*.csv", recursive=T))
```

Which results to:

```
[1] "just_one.csv" "just_two.csv"
```